# How to get multiple values from JDBC response using Groovy Script

Tags: xml, jdbc, groovy, soapui

let's say I have response from JDBC step

```
<Results>
    <ResultSet fetchSize="0">
        <Row rowNumber="1">
            <CONTINENTS.ID>2</CONTINENTS.ID>
            <CONTINENTS.CONTINENT_CODE>AN</CONTINENTS.CONTINENT_CODE>
            <CONTINENTS.CONTINENT_NAME>Antarctica</CONTINENTS.CONTINENT_NAME>
        </Row>
    </ResultSet>
</Results>
```

I want to get each variable name and value from JDBC response and set on the "Properties" TestStep so it would look like that. However I want it to be dynamical (if in response would be a another variables like LANGUAGE_NAME, CAPITAL_CITY_NAME and so on it would also get their names and values and set them on the Properties TestStep). How can I achieve that?
["Properties" TestStep](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhwFQ.png)